# How to get the HostName or the Device name of devices connected to my LAN through android?

Tags: java, android, android-networking

I'm making an android app that gets a list of all the devices connected to my lan(as their IPs and MACs), something similar to what the app Fing does.

Now what I want to do is get the host names of the devices on my LAN. For example -

The IP address "192.168.1.221" returns host name "Sherlock".

Here Sherlock is the device name (or the host name) of my pc.

I have already tried

- InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.221").getHostName();
- InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.221").getCanonicalHostName();

But these keep returning the IP address itself.

Can anyone please help me with the right way? Probably there is some Linux command that I could run in Runtime. Anything that helps.

Thanks in advance :)